# Are there any resourceful sites for finding album booklet scans?

Tags: cd, artwork

I've been searching for a while now and haven't had any luck finding a site that's:

1. Frequently updated
2. Posts an entire album booklet vs. front/back or partial scans

Aside from purchasing the album in-store or on iTunes does anyone have a comprehensive and resourceful site that manages to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, this question promotes illegal downloads and is against the rules.  I'll leave it open to see if anyone can come up with **legal** resources or covers that a band may post online (I think Smashing Pumpkins did this for one release), but any "repository" websites will be edited and the links removed.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware that album art copyrights were setup where images couldn't be uploaded to the Web.

Comment: Try www.discogs.com. They have some album scans for some albums, but it's generally pretty hit or miss, especially since you might have to search through dozens of versions of the same album to find a full album scan (if one actually does exist).